# One-time bindings in templates doesn't work with a space on beginning

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very strange problem with One-time bindings in templates.
In definition if I want to use it, I need to starting an expression with ::.

```
{{ ::expression }}
```

Normally it should works, but for me stopped working. If I remove space before :: and do something like:

```
{{:: expression }}
```

It works. No idea why. To check how many watchers are created I use a AngularJS Batarang for Chrome and own JS script to calculate watchers. The both works the same.
I think that the both tools works correctly, because I see that when amount of watchers is big, the app works very slow.

Does anyone has something similar? Thanks!

Comment: What is the meaning of `::expression`? Never saw that in Angular... Oo'

Comment: You can see here: https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/

Comment: @SlawomirJ We are having the exact same issue with angular 1.5.8 + webpack. However if we create a simple example in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mbdgjw) the problem disappears. What's your configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a heavy debugging session, and it turns out it's actually Batarang that's breaking the one-time binding.

Batarang uses [Angular Hint](https://github.com/angular/angular-hint) to hook into the angular lifecycle to get an idea of what's going on.
There is an open issue there about one-time bindings:
https://github.com/angular/angular-hint/issues/109

The issue is quite old old (though still open)...and it looks like they [added in code](https://github.com/angular/angular-hint/blob/master/src/modules/scopes.js#L358) to try and fix the issue but it's not quite robust enough.
This is why it works when you do `{{::` and not `{{ ::`

**The good news** is you don't need to worry about your app, those one-time bindings are working in production (unless your users also have Batarang enabled).

**The bad news** is you can't rely on Batarang to be truthful about the watchers right now, and be wary that it could cause other bugs/issues because it's replacing angular code.

*As an aside, the codepen works fine because it's running inside an iframe, so batarang is unable to get to it and break it.*